# How can make this join of two huge MySQL Tables finish?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I have two tables

**table1:**

> ```
> column1: varchar(20)
> column2: varchar(20)
> column3: varchar(20)
> ```

**table2:**

> ```
> column1: varchar(20)
> column2: varchar(20)
> column3: varchar(20) <- empty
> ```

- column1 and column2 both have a separate Fulltext index in table1
- both tables hold 20 million rows

I need to fill `column3` of `table2` by matching `column1` & `column2` from `table2` to `column1` & `column2` from `table1`, then take the value in `column3` from `table1` and put it into `column3` of `table2`. `column1` & `column2` might not match exactly, so the query I use for this is:

```
UPDATE table1, table2 
SET table2.column3 = table1.column3 
WHERE table2.column1 LIKE table1.'%column1%' AND 
      table2.column2 LIKE table1.'%column2%';
```

This query never finishes. I let it run for 2 weeks and still didn't produce any result. It utilized one CPU core 100%, had little SSD IO and apparently needs to be optimized somehow.

I am open to any suggestions regarding query optimization, index optimization or even DBMS optimization (or even migration, if it helps) since I need to do queries like this more often in the future.

**EDIT1**

> There are plenty of optimization guides, please use google for that. You can increase the threads in config (InnoDB). For the Update itself i recommend to first create a temp_table and then copy to db2

I know that but couldn't quite solve my scenario with those guides. I also know that questions of all possible permutations of combinations for this problem (huge databases, performance, bottlenecks, query design) are all around, also on stackoverflow. However, to this day I couldn't figure out what the best way to proceed would be for this specific combination of problems and hoped for getting help here. That being said:
- more threads would require sharding or partitioning in order to utilize more than one CPU core, which I would like to avoid if I can solve the problem with other means
- how would you propose to create such temporary table here?

> Why do you use like operator if you do not use wild card characters? Replace them with =. Also, do you have multi-column index on the 3 columns in the where criteria in each of the tables? Pls share the output of the explain as well, along with any existing indexes in the 2 tables.

- I left those characters out in the example but want to use them once the basic query works, sorry for the confusion. I am not entirely sure how to put those wildcards into a column comparison though.
- I have two seperate indizes, should I create a 2-column index instead? (there are only 2 columns in the where criteria)
- would you rather have the explain of the structure I have now or prefer the explain of the structure with a 2-column index?

> i guess you say databases but you are talking about tables, right?

Exactly, sorry for the confusion.

> The query you wrote will perform 20m x 20m lookups (for each row in table 1 look up all rows in table 2). You can't write whatever in and expect it to work if you have an SSD or a good CPU. If you arrived at this point, it's time to think before you start writing SQL. What it is that you need to do, what are the tools you have at your disposal and what's the middle part that you don't know - those are the questions you need to answer every time before you issue 400 billion lookup query.

That is the scenario I am facing though. I don't expect it to work at all like it is at the moment, to be honest, so I am looking for pointers which might make this a solvable scenario. The basic "update this, where that matches" query apparently doesn't apply here. So I am trying to figure out a way to a more advanced solution. Any criticism is very welcome, so thank you for this input. How would you suggest to proceed here?

**EDIT2**

> Give us some sample values and non-exact comparisons.

**table1:**

```
+---------+---------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3     | column4 | column5 | columnN |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| John    | Doe_    | employee001 | xyz     | 12345   | ...     |
| Jim     | Doe     | employee002 | abc     | 67890   | ...     |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**table2:**

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| John    | Doe     |         |
| Jim     | Doe     |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Here, a LIKE query would fill both rows of table 2, if it would match "Doe_" for "Doe". But by writing this down, I just realized that a LIKE query is no option here because the variations wouldn't constrain to a suffix of column2 in table 1, rather various possible likes would be required (leading AND trailing variants for both columns in both tables). This in turn would multiply the number of required matches.
So let's forget about the LIKE and concentrate on exact matching only.

> FULLTEXT and LIKE have nothing to do with each other.
>
> "Might not match exactly" -- You will need more limitations on this non-restriction. Else, any attempt at a query will continue to take weeks.
>
> t2.c1 LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.c1, '%') requires checking ever row of t1 against every row of t2; that's 400 trillion tests. No hardware can do that in a reasonable length of time.
>
> FULLTEXT works with "words". If your c1 and c2 are strings of words, then there is some hope to use FULLTEXT. FULLTEXT is much faster than LIKE because it has an index structure based on words.
>
> However, even FULLTEXT is no where near the speed of t2.c1 = t1.c1. Still, that would need a composite INDEX(c1, c2) Then it would be a full table scan (20M rows) of one table, plus 20M probes via a BTree index into the other table. This is like 40M operations -- a lot better than 400T for LIKE.
>
> In order to proceed, please think through your definition of "Might not match exactly" and present the best you can live with.

Ok, since I decided to drop the LIKE requirement, what exactly do you propose to use as index?
I read your post like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `indexname1` (`column1`, `column2`);

ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `indexname2` (`column1`, `column2`);

UPDATE `table1`, `table2` 
SET `table2`.`column3` = `table1`.`column3 `
WHERE CONCAT(`table1`.`column1`, `table1`.`column2`) = CONCAT(`table2`.`column1`, `table2`.`column2`);
```

Is this correct?

Two followup questions though:
1) Is the update in your oppinion as fast, faster or slower as creating a new table, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE `merged` AS
SELECT `table1`.`column1`, `table1`.`column2`, `table1`.`column3`
FROM `table1`, `table2`
WHERE CONCAT(`table1`.`column1`, `table1`.`column2`) = CONCAT(`table2`.`column1`, `table2`.`column2`);
```

2) Would the indizes and / or the matching be case sensitive? If yes, can adapt the query without having to change column1 & column2 to all upper case (or all lower case)?

Comment: There are plenty of optimization guides, please use google for that. You can increase the threads in config (InnoDB). For the Update itself i recommend to first create a temp_table and then copy to db2

Comment: Why do you use like operator if you do not use wild card characters? Replace them with `=`. Also, do you have multi-column index on the 3 columns in the where criteria in each of the tables? Pls share the output of the explain as well, along with any existing indexes in the 2 tables.

Comment: i guess you say databases but you are talking about tables, right?

Comment: The query you wrote will perform 20m x 20m lookups (for each row in table 1 look up all rows in table 2). You can't write whatever in and expect it to work if you have an SSD or a good CPU. If you arrived at this point, it's time to think before you start writing SQL. What it is that you *need* to do, what are the tools you have at your disposal and what's the middle part that you don't know - those are the questions you need to answer every time before you issue 400 billion lookup query.

Comment: Give us some sample values and non-exact comparisons.

Comment: I updated the description accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FULLTEXT` and `LIKE` have nothing to do with each other.

"Might not match exactly" -- You will need more limitations on this non-restriction.  Else, any attempt at a query will continue to take weeks.

`t2.c1 LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.c1, '%')` requires checking ever row of t1 against every row of t2; that's 400 *trillion* tests.  No hardware can do that in a reasonable length of time.

`FULLTEXT` works with "words".  If your c1 and c2 are strings of words, then there is some hope to use `FULLTEXT`.  `FULLTEXT` is much faster than `LIKE` because it has an index structure based on words.

However, even `FULLTEXT` is no where near the speed of `t2.c1 = t1.c1`.  Still, that would need a *composite* `INDEX(c1, c2)`  Then it would be a full table scan (20M rows) of one table, plus 20M probes via a BTree index into the other table.  This is like 40M operations -- a lot better than 400T for `LIKE`.

In order to proceed, please think through your definition of "Might not match exactly" and present the best you can live with.

**Edit**

`WHERE CONCAT(t1.c1, t1.c2) = CONCAT(t2.c1, t2.c2)` is a *lot* worse than saying `WHERE t1.c1=t2.c2 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2`.  The latter will run fast with `INDEX(c1,c2)`.

Comment: Rick, I just found your blog which is EXCELLENT! You should have just pointed me to that for reference and I could have spared the rest of the commenters with my puny questions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
1. Add a new column to db1 and db2 with a **character, that never appears** in column1 and column2, for example **@**

```
ALTER TABLE `db1` ADD  `column4` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ;

UPDATE db1 SET column4 = column1 + '@' + column2
```

2. Do the same for db2. Then create an index (BTREE) on column 4 (in db1 and db2).

```
ALTER TABLE  `db1` ADD INDEX (  `column4` ) ;

ALTER TABLE  `db2` ADD INDEX (  `column4` ) ;
```

3. Then run next query:

```
UPDATE db1, db2 SET db2.column3 = db1.column3 WHERE db1.column4 = db2.column4;
```

It should run fast enough.
When it's done - just drop column4 and it's index

Comment: (Use `CONCAT(...)` instead of `+` in MySQL's variant of SQL.)